# More or less proper converting from RGB to CMYK

Tags: html, printing, canvas, rgb, cmyk

I am working on an [app](http://www.cardolio.com) that saves canvas content as a raster image, then user saves it to his computer to print with a printer or print office. If you visit the link, you can click button Export and click the link to save the file. I know I can't handle CMYK with canvas and the file is sent as RGB. But I can control color values that are used for generating the image. For example, if I know that some object is any shade of black, I can put it on a separate layer and then join black layer and colored layer together on server side. May be it can help with the issue. So, I wonder if any of you faced a similar challenge to generate color-accurate image ready for print with canvas. Or may be using SVG can help me by any chance? Please share your hints.

Note: I use Python as a server-side language but I think any language library/solution will work for me if it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

CMYK is always dependant on the kind of paper. E.g. the total ink for very dark color tones might be around 350% on glossy paper, but only 200% on coated paper. So you have to know the target medium in advance. There is no 1:1 conversion from RGB to CMYK.

Nowadays most printers handle RGB just fine, I wonder why you really need to do the separation at all.

If you insist on converting to CMYK, have a look at http://cue.yellowmagic.info/softwares/separate-plus/index.html for a possibility to do that with a GIMP plugin. I am quite sure that it is scriptable server-side.